# Trying to build apk and these error occur: Flutter Firebase.app(appName) error, Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, apk

I am getting these errors

```
This is one of many:
1.Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'Firebase'.
        FirebaseFirestorePlatform.instanceFor(app: Firebase.app(appName));
2.This error comes at the end:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
```

I was trying to get longitude and latitude from firebase and was retrieving it for sometime then I tried to build an APK of the app, unfortunately while doing that errors the above error appeared and now I can't even run my app on emulator.

I tried every thing I could find online and in forums but nothing has worked for me yet, I tried removing the firebase completely from my app and it works fine but as soon as I put the code of firebase again the same errors occur, I don't understanf if the problem is with plugin or anything else but the problem only started to occur after I tried to build an APK.

This is the code that I am using:

MapScreen2:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

import 'SearchScreen.dart';

class MapScreen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapScreen2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MapScreen2> createState() => _MapScreen2State();
}


class _MapScreen2State extends State<MapScreen2> {
  static const _initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(24.923816, 67.098588),
    zoom: 11.5,
  );

  Completer <GoogleMapController> _googleMapController= Completer();

  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
  void initMarkers(specify, specifyID) async{
    var markerIDVal = specifyID;
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIDVal);
    final Marker marker = Marker(
        markerId: markerId,
        position: LatLng(specify['Latitude'], specify['Longitude']),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Data'),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker
    );
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId]=marker;
    });
  }

  getMarkerData()async{
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Location').get().then((myMockData){
      if(myMockData.docs.isNotEmpty){
        for (int i=0; i<myMockData.docs.length;i++){
          initMarkers(myMockData.docs[i].data(), myMockData.docs[i].id);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  Future<Position> getUserCurrentLocation() async{
    await Geolocator.requestPermission().then((value){
    }).onError((error, stackTrace){
      print("error"+error.toString());
    });
    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    getMarkerData();
    super.initState();
    // loadData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          icon: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(26, 26, 26, 1),
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(230, 230, 230, 1),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(26, 26, 26, 1),
        foregroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(230, 230, 230, 1),
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 26
        ),
        title: const Text("Pothole Map"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 800,
            child: GoogleMap(
              zoomControlsEnabled: false,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
              markers:Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
              //markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers),
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _googleMapController.complete(controller);
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextField(
                          onTap: (){
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>SearchScreen(),
                              fullscreenDialog: true,
                            ),
                            );
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Where To?',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(191, 191, 191, 1),fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 22),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(26, 26, 26, 1),
                          ),
                          autofocus: false,
                          showCursor: false,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(26, 26, 26, 1),
        foregroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(230, 230, 230, 1),
        onPressed: () async{
          getUserCurrentLocation().then((value)async{
            CameraPosition cameraPosition=CameraPosition(
                zoom: 14,
                target: LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude)
            );
            final GoogleMapController controller= await _googleMapController.future;
            controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            setState(() {});
          });
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.navigation),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

main:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart%20%20';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'MapScreen2.dart';
import 'SearchScreen.dart';

void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Google Map',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(26, 26, 26, 1),
        foregroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(230, 230, 230, 1),
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 26
        ),
        title: const Text("Pothole Map"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextField(
                          onTap: (){
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>MapScreen2(),
                              fullscreenDialog: true,
                            ),
                            );
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Map',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 22),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(26, 26, 26, 1),
                          ),
                          autofocus: false,
                          showCursor: false,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        TextField(
                          onTap: (){
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>SearchScreen(),
                              fullscreenDialog: true,
                            ),
                            );
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Where To?',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color:Color.fromRGBO(191, 191, 191, 1),fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 22),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(26, 26, 26, 1),
                          ),
                          autofocus: false,
                          showCursor: false,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        TextField(
                          onTap: (){
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Feedback',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(191, 191, 191, 1),fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 22),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(26, 26, 26, 1),
                          ),
                          autofocus: false,
                          showCursor: false,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

pubsec.yaml:

```
name: new_final_app
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.5 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  dio: ^4.0.0
  flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  geocoding: ^2.0.4
  http:
  uuid: ^3.0.5
  google_place: ^0.4.7
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.11.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.3.0
  firebase_database: ^10.0.8
  firebase_core: ^2.4.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.3

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/image.jpeg"

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0


flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/pothole.png
  uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 0):

So the code worked for me after a few changes first configure your firebase through Firebase CLI and configure the "firebase cli" with npm option, it worked for me, after that if you have previously configured your app through android option only than remove all the configurations such as json file given by firebase and all other dependencies as well. I hope this question and answer helps anyone who is facing the problem. I will provide all the links which helped me,

How to install firebase cli:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#setup_update_cli

Video guide on how to install firebase cli:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7mpIlF2L7w&t=474s&ab_channel=FlutterForce

and try to use vscode while using "flutterfire configure" because I don't know why but this command didn't work for me in android studio.